Zscaler api to check status of publicaly accessible trust.zscaler.com
I want to check the status of zsclaer saas of a particular region priodicaly on trust.zscaler.com which is the publically accessible page and should not require any authentication .
Can someone help me with the API i can use .
I am unable to find the API responsible for it.
